# Firebase for Flutter sign-in build failure

Tags: flutter

I have been following the Firebase for Flutter tutorial with success until I reach "Set up Firebase Integration". When I relaunch the app on my phone the build fails with the following exception:

> Note:
>   /Users/williamdevore/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-0.0.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/storage/FirebaseStoragePlugin.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. /Users/williamdevore/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-0.0.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlesignin/GoogleSignInPlugin.java:30:
>   error: cannot find symbol import
>   io.flutter.app.FlutterFragmentActivity;
>                        ^   symbol:   class FlutterFragmentActivity   location: package io.flutter.app
>   /Users/williamdevore/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-0.0.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlesignin/GoogleSignInPlugin.java:98:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                 + FlutterFragmentActivity.class.getName());
>                   ^   symbol:   class FlutterFragmentActivity   location: class GoogleSignInPlugin 2 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Flutter doctor says everything is fine for Android. I have the latest "everything". I was able to setup the google-services json file and use the Firebase console with no problems.

I followed the instructions for modifying the build.gradle files exactly--twice!.

Is there some of other step I should be doing outside of the Flutter tutorial that is specific for Android, perhaps Brew or cocoapods maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have an older version of Flutter that doesn't match the Google Sign In plugin version you're using. Right now the plugins aren't declaring which versions of Flutter they require (but that may change in the future).

Does running `flutter update` get you past this error? If not, try running `flutter doctor` and see how old your Flutter SDK is. You want it to include the commit [b4ba972bf394a2269824e1eadaa1627bbc872d4b](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/b4ba972bf394a2269824e1eadaa1627bbc872d4b), so it should be a few days old at most.

You should replace `FlutterActivity` with `FlutterFragmentActivity` in the two places it appears in your `MainActivity.java`. (This won't be necessary in the next Google Sign In plugin update; see [issue 10690](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10690).)

Comment: Thanks Collin. Running `flutter upgrade` fixed the issue but now the app keeps **stopping** with no error messages. I am trying to any kind of log file  but the only one I find is for the flutter build process. Would you happen to know of any log files to search?

Comment: You might want to change `flutter update` to `flutter upgrade` in your response. That threw me off for a second.

Comment: Don't try to upgrade flutter on existing project..You will surely regret if u new to flutter